# frequency to time conversion using MATLAB

Tags: excel, matlab, fft, ifft

I would like to convert my data in frequency domain into time domain. In this attached excel sheet (book1.xlxs) Column A is Frequency. Column B and C is real and imaginary data (B+jC). Also attached you can see my code. But its not working.  I would like to have the my result something shown in figure in time domain (green curve part-1).

```
[num, data, raw] = xlsread('Book1.xlsx');
ln=length(raw)-1; %find the length of the sequence
xk=zeros(1,ln); %initilise an array of same size as that of input sequence
ixk=zeros(1,ln); %initilise an array of same size as that of input sequence
rx = zeros(1,ln); %real value of fft
ix = zeros(1,ln); %imaginary value of fft
for i= 2:length(raw)
rx(i-1) = cell2mat(raw(i,2));
ix(i-1) = cell2mat(raw(i,3));
xk(i-1) = sqrt(rx(i-1)^2 + ix(i-1)^2);
end
for n=0:ln-1
for k=0:ln-1
    ixk(n+1)=ixk(n+1)+(xk(k+1)*exp(i*2*pi*k*n/ln));
end
end

ixk=10*log(ixk./ln);

t=0:ln-1
plot(t, ixk)
```

[In this image this code should give me the result similar to the green curve-part1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elNNw.png)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing the FFT yourself, you could use the built-in Matlab functions to do it - much easier.

A good example from Mathworks is given [here](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/amplitude-estimation-and-zero-padding.html). The following is some code I have based myself on. The passed-in parameter `f` is your time domain trace, and `fsampling` is your sampling rate. The passed-out parameters `freq` and `finv` are your frequency vector and fourier transform, respectively.

```
function [freq, finv] = FourierTransform(f,fsampling)

    % Fast Fourier Transform

    fsampling = round(fsampling);
    finv = fft(f,fsampling);
    finv = finv(1:length(finv)/2+1); % Truncate out only the second half, due to symmetry
    finv(2:end - 1) = 2*finv(2:end - 1); % Adjust amplitude to account for truncation
    finv = finv./length(f);
    freq = 0:fsampling/2;

end
```